# Does Victor Meyer test distinguish alcohols and alkyl halides?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I read from a source that alkyl halides and alcohols cannot be differentiated by the Victor Meyer test. It says that both react similarly with the reagents and form the same products. Is this correct, and if so what are the reactions for alkyl halides.

Comment: What do you mean by reactions for alkyl halides? Afaik victor Meyer test is primilarily used to differentiate *between* 1°, 2° and 3° alcohols and not to differentiate *alcohols from* alkyl halides. (It's even not an effective test for 3° alcohols because they along with phenols and enols, do not respond positively to this test).

Comment: Well, as of what I have read, alkyl halides and alcohols are said to react in the same way with the reagents used for Victor Meyer test. That's what I've asked.

Comment: @AaronJohnSabu Just "as far as I have read" doesn't cut it. We invite you to logically decide whether its really apt or not. If you're confused, come over here and ask, mention exactly why you're conflicted.

Comment: I wanted to know if it was really apt or not. I am conflicted because I want to know whether alkyl halides undergo the same reactions. I want to confirm it.

Answer (score 3):

Aaron,

You could be correct if your alkyl halides to be ditinguished are 1,2,3 degree alkyl IODIDES.
Because we ultimately are converting 1,2,3 degree alcohols into IODIDES in step-I; followed by reactions with NaNO2/HCl and then NaOH.

@Pritt Balagopal

He had a valid point, when he said "alkyl halides and alcohols are said to react in the same way with the reagents used for Victor Meyer test"